# Depth of $i$-th syzygy module, where $i$ is at most the depth of the ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring of depth $t\ge 1$. So for any finitely generated free $R$-module $F$, we have $\operatorname {depth}(F)=\operatorname {depth}(R)=t$.

My question:

> If $0\ne M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module which fits into an exact sequence $0\to M \to F_{i-1}\to \dots\to F_1\to F_0$, where $1\le i\le t$ and $F_i$ are finitely generated free $R$-modules,  then how to show that $\operatorname {depth}(M)\ge i$  ?

I can easily show this if $t=1$ or $2$.

Also, for $i=1$ (irrespective of $t$) , since $0\to M\to F_0$ and $\operatorname {depth}(F_0)=\operatorname {depth}(R)=t\ge 1$ and submodules of modules of depth $\ge 1$ always has depth $\ge 1$, so in that case $\operatorname {depth}(M)\ge 1$.

But I'm unable to do anything for higher values of $t$.

Please help.

Comment: Can you show that if we have an exact sequence $0\to K\to F\to M\to 0$ with depth of $M=r<t$, and $F$ free, then depth of $K=r+1$?

Comment: Would the characterisation of depth in terms of the vanishing of the Ext functor help?

Comment: @Mohan: I can definitely show that ... now to apply that in my scenario inductively say to $0\to M\to F_{i-1}\to N\to 0$ where $N=Im\{F_{i-1}\to F_{i-2} \}=\ker \{F_{i-2}\to F_{i-3}\}$,                                                          
  so $N$ is an $i-1$-th syzygy module ... but by induction hypothesis we only know $\operatorname{depth}(N)\ge i-1$ and I'm not sure why $\operatorname{depth}(N)< t$ ...

Comment: @Angina Seng: I'm not sure how it'd of help directly (of-course I'm using Ext a lot while proving some estimates for example the one connected by Mohan) ...

Comment: @Mohan: agh I think I see it now ... if depth of $N$ $\ge t$, then depth of $M$ is $\ge t$ and we're done any way , so then we can assume depth of $N$ $< t$ , and then also we're done by what you said ...